# Why can the term $k/a^2$ in the Friedmann equations be neglected for inflation models?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, approximations

I am currently reading the TASI Lectures on Inflation [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.5424.pdf). Deriving the Friedmann equations one gets (with $c = 1$)

$H^2 = \frac{4\pi G}{3}\rho - \frac{k}{a^2}$.

But when talking about inflation with one scalar field, the last term is dropped (on page 32). This term is negligible for large $a$, but I dont see why this assumption is justified. Especially, because this term causes the flatness problem in the first place. Can someone explain why this approximation is valid?

Comment: Can you provide a specific section in which the last term is dropped, just for reference?

Comment: yes sure. I added the relevant page.

Comment: So is your concern that the second half of (67) should read $H^2=\frac{8\pi G\rho}{3}\left(\frac12\dot{\phi}^2+V(\phi)\right)-\frac{k}{a^2(\phi)}$?

Comment: yes my concern is why this term is missing or why one can assume that its small enough to be neglected.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have included a $\rho$ factor there. My suggestion is the $k$ term is absorbed into the definition of $V$.